# How to edit specific pixel in image using PHP

Tags: php, image-processing

I want to know how can I edit some part in image and color them?
I found tutorials on how to add watermarks or text but what I want to do is modify (*change color of*) a single pixel at a specific x/y position inside a picture.

Please help me I'm beginner.

Comment: What do you mean by "frame"? Are you working with an animated (GIF) image?

Comment: @rickdenhaan sorry I mistakenly used the word frame, I meant image is made of small pixels. So I want to color a small pixel

Comment: You can use [`imagesetpixel`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesetpixel.php) to change the color of an individual pixel. You can also use functions like [`imageline`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imageline.php), [`imagerectangle`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerectangle.php), [`imageellipse`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imageellipse.php) or [`imagepolygon`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepolygon.php) to draw basic shapes.

Comment: Thanks for reply. It's working !